# Overloading a member function to receive an assigned value?

Tags: c++, overloading, assignment-operator

I want to create two methods of a class that access and modify some data in that instance.

For example:

```
int val = image.at(row, col);
image.at(row, col) = 255;
```

Is there a way to overload the function so it allows assignment when calling `image.at(row,col)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to write 2 methods for this. So long as `at` returns a value that can be assigned to (i.e. an l-value), the same function will work to both access and modify the data:

```
struct Image 
{
   int& at(int, int);
// ^^^^ 
};
```

However, you should provide an overload for the case when the object whose data you want to access is a const object:

```
struct Image 
{
   int& at(int, int);
   int const& at(int, int) const;  // for const objects
};
```

Comment: One could also have two versions for `const` and non `const` instances. That would prevent from wondering why the `at()` function won't work in specific situations. That's _best practice_ IIRC.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Good point, added. Yes, it certainly is good practice.